# Canvas view not going below any view

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

My activity is in LANDSCAPE mode
I am using following code.

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/sample"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:text="saga"/> 
<com.example.sample.Circle
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:background="#AD9999"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/sample"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends View{

public Circle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
}

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=context;
    mOuterDialPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    float width=canvas.getWidth()/2;
    Log.i("Width", ""+canvas.getHeight());
    float dialCenterX=width;
    canvas.drawCircle(dialCenterX, canvas.getHeight(), dialCenterX, mOuterDialPaint);
}
}
```

So canvas is drawing circle from specified positions but not moving below textview so textview is coming on top of canvas and some part is getting cut. So any fix for this problem??

Comment: you should use framelayout instead of relative layout, would be a good option in this situation.

Comment: Height you have not specified . but you are calling canvas.getHeight() ?

Comment: @PreethiRao: Yaa but whn I log canvas.getHeight(), I am getting different height for different devices. I dont think that is issue here..

Comment: @KaranMer: How do I specify layout_below then??

Comment: @Rohit : chk out the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Use frame-Layout in xml:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.example.sample.Circle
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#AD9999" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="your text view" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: THnx But I have to bring that semi circle below text view only.. It should not overlal textviews height....

Comment: can you post screen shot of your layout.?